# How to update which template is shown based on what the user selects from the select box with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a page that dynamically loads a template based on the option that the user chooses from a select box.  I currently have it loading the template on page load but after that it does not change based on user action.

```
.directive('ngUsersearch', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function($compile, $http, $templateCache) {

    var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
        var templateLoader,
        baseUrl = 'view2/components/',
        templateMap = {
            beer: 'beerList.html',
            brewery: 'breweryList.html',
            event: 'eventList.html',
            guild: 'guildList.html'
        };

        var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[contentType];
        templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache});

        return templateLoader;

    }

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var loader = getTemplate(scope.ngModel);

        var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
            element.html(html);
        }).then(function (response) {
            element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
        });

    }

     return {
         restrict:"E",
         scope: {
            ngModel: '='
         },
         link: linker
     }
 }]);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="userFilter">      
    <option value="beer">Beer</option>
    <option value="brewery">Brewery</option>
    <option value="event">Event</option>
    <option value="guild">Guild</option>
</select>
<ng-usersearch ng-model="userFilter"></ng-usersearch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me. I switched the way that the directive was loading the template.  This can be done at the link function, but after the directive is set up and a part of the DOM, I was trying to remove the directive itself from the DOM by replacing it, which does not play well with how Angular's selectors work. So, now I am just replacing its contents. Also, in order to get the ng-repeat to work within the custom directive I had to add the search-results='searchResults' and then define that in the directives scope as well.

HTML:

```
<ng-usersearch ng-model="userFilter" search-results='searchResults'></ng-usersearch>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', [ '$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {

    $scope.userSearch = "";

    $scope.userFilter = "beer";

    $scope.search = function(userSearch, userFilter) {

        $scope.searchResults = ("No " + userFilter + " Information Available");

        Restangular.all('search?q=' + userSearch + '&type=' + userFilter + '&withBreweries=Y').customGET().then(function(data) {
            $scope.searchResults = data;
        });
    };

}])
```

Directive:

```
.directive('ngUsersearch', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', function($http, $templateCache, $compile) {

    var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
        var templateLoader,
        baseUrl = 'view2/components/',
        templateMap = {
            all: 'all.html',
            beer: 'beerList.html',
            brewery: 'breweryList.html',
            event: 'eventList.html',
            guild: 'guildList.html'
        };

        var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[contentType];
        templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache.get()});

        return templateLoader;

    }

    var link = function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            var loader = getTemplate(newValue);
            var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
                var rendered = $compile(html)(scope);
                element.empty();
                element.append(rendered);               });
        });

    }

     return {
         restrict:"E",
         scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            searchResults: '='
         },
         link: link
     }
}]);
```

I hope this helps other coders because I struggled with this for a day.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot listen the change event of the model;

```
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      var loader = getTemplate(newValue);
      var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
          element.html(html);
      }).then(function (response) {
          element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope)); // you compile and you have isolated scope?
      });
    });
}
```

on your compile the only scope available would be ngModel

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I implemented this and was still having an issue.  It takes the first option that I select but if I select another option it still displays the first selected template.  I figured out a solution to it where I am no longer getting an error.  It is based off of your solution.